# Mobile HTML5 Frameworks

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova, sencha-touch

I need to know the best suited mobile frameworks which greatly exploits  the functionalities of HTML5. Some of the choices I have are:

1. PhoneGap
2. JQuery Mobile
3. Sencha Touch

Can you friends just guide me based on the experience you have with mobile apps development
Thanks

Comment: In case you want to close the question doesn't matter, but at least leave a comment and tell what's wrong with my question so that next time I don't make the same mistake, thanks :)

Comment: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit **opinion**, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion."

Comment: This blog post explains why this is a bad question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: Ok, I read the blog and ensure that in future, the question is a good question, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some specific facts that might help you would be to compare the documentation for each of the frameworks. I've found that how a mobile framework is documented is the number 1 thing that is important to me when i get deep into it. So here are the links to each of the documentations.

[PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/index.html)
[JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)
[Sencha Touch](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/)

Consequently, you may want to familiarize exactly WHAT constitutes a "mobile" framework. For example, i use both phonegap AND sencha touch. So take some time to read up on exactly what's what. Sometimes you can use multiple frameworks together.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a framework, you may want to try Tiggr Mobile Apps Builder - http://gotiggr.com. It's a cloud service for building HTML5 and native apps. The builder uses jQuery Mobile, and PhoneGap (for native).

Note: I work for Exadel, the company behind Tiggr.